# How to obtain new authorization code for Google Cloud Server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Good day!

We have a Google Cloud Platform server and we need to obtain a new authorization code. We currently don't have local developer support for this server anymore. How to do this? A simple step-by-step guide will be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: What is an authorization code? Edit your question to clearly state what you are asking. Show what work/research you have done and what problems you are having.  Read this page to help you improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi John, Sorry for the confusion. We have this setup where PO files are created via salesforce, then these PO files are pushed to an FTP site via php script hosted in google cloud server. Last Jan. 17 the PO are no longer pushed to the FTP and upon investigation, we found out that when salesforce attempts to connect to google cloud server, the reply was invalid authorization code. Salesforce dev support advised that we need to obtain a new authorization code from google.

Comment: We current;y don't have developer support for the google cloud server and community support is only available. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you know where is deployed your server, which product are you using? (app engine, cloud functions, compute engine)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such authorization code to connect to an instance I assume you are not authenticating correctly to your GCP instance (user/password, SSH keys etc).

Here is a step by step [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6YmQYf3WBA) to connect a FTP server to your instance , basically you generate a [SSH key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) and added in your instance metadata.

If this doesn't work I suggest you to edit your question adding more information such as FTP client you are using, error you are receiving, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Ernesto U, I'm able to connect to the GCP instance via web browser. There is an API created in Salesforce and that connects to the GCP instance and now it cannot connect because of the error that authorization code was invalid. I guess we have to generate an authorization code from GCP then set it on Salesforce for the API to connect successfully. I'm still checking on how to do this but I'm hoping someone would point me to the right direction here on how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Brix I believe this issue is within the SalesForce API. On GCP there is no such item as "authorization code" there are tokens which is kinda similar. I did a quick research into a SalesForce API there is an authentication method for "authorization code" hope this helps https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_social.meta/api_social/3-authorization-code.htm
If you can share the name of the API you are using it will help to understand the issue

Comment: Hi Ernesto, Salesforce dev support advised us that we can obtain the authorization code from Google. He mentioned there is nothing wrong with Salesforce since the call out from Salesforce is successful and the response from GCP is invalid authorization code. The name of the API is PHP_Utility_App.

Comment: Hi Ernesto, checked with Salesforce dev support the shared article and it is related to marketing cloud. We don't use this and as per him, it is not related to the current issue. Hope you could help me point to the correct direction. Thanks.

Comment: @BrixG - First, you need to figure out what is meant by authorization code and what service is returning this code. Then figure out how your app is designed and what kind of authorization is being performed. As written your question does not have an answer because you do not have a clear definition of the problem.

Comment: Hi John,
I wish I could explain this in detail but apology for I'm not a developer but putting best effort to provide information about my question.
Here is a part of the code that requires the authorization code, this one is from Salesforce side and it contacts the google cloud server for the code.

Comment: public static Boolean sendToFTPAPI(String fileName, String fileData){
        if(fileData != null && fileName != null){
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(FTP_SFDC_Configuration.FTP_POTEXTFILES_ENDPOINT);
            request.setMethod('POST');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            request.setHeader('Authorization-Token', 'numeric value');//Please do not change this value
           
This is part of the Salesforce apex code which connects to GCP.